# Java NullPointerException when using super.paintComponent(g); in public void paintComponent(){}

Tags: java, graphics, nullpointerexception, paintcomponent

I've been experimenting with graphics in java but when I tried to run my code it gave me the NullPointerException error on the line with `paintComponent(g);` in it. I was trying to set the `Graphics g` in the method `paintComponent` and I created an enemy script that was pretty much the same and it still not working. I checked with the internet but there was only one and they used a thread completely changing the structure of this code. here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:800)
    at com.arena.game.food.paintComponent(food.java:12)
    at com.arena.game.food.<init>(food.java:27)
    at com.arena.game.Game.foodSpawn(Game.java:8)
    at com.arena.game.Game.main(Game.java:24)
```

Here is the actual code:

```
package com.arena.game;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Game {
    public static void foodSpawn(int diff, int w, int h, Window W) {
        while(true) {
            W.newFood(new food(diff,w,h));
            try {TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(20000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int width = 300;
        int height =  300;
        int diff = 1;
        int squareS = 100;
        int x = width/2-squareS/2;
        int y = height/2-squareS/2;
        int velx = ran.nextInt(15)+1;
        int vely = ran.nextInt(15)+1;
        Enemy f = new Enemy(squareS);
        Window win = new Window(width,height,f);
        foodSpawn(diff,width,height,win);
        while(true) {
            if (x >= width-squareS || x<=0) {velx=-velx; diff++; velx++; x=x+velx;} else {x=x+velx;}
            if (y >= height-squareS || y<=0) {vely=-vely; diff++; vely++; y=y+vely;} else {y=y+vely;}
            f.newxy(x,y);
            width = Window.newW();
            height = Window.newH();
        }
    }
}
package com.arena.game;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Window extends JFrame{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    public static int getW;
    public static int getH;
    public void newFood(food f) {
        super.add(f);
    }
    public Window(int width,int height,Enemy f) {
        getW = width;
        getH = height;
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        super.add(f);
        super.setSize(width, height);
        super.setVisible(true);
        super.getContentPane().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                Component c = (Component)e.getSource();
                int W = c.getWidth();
                int H = c.getHeight();
                getW = W;
                getH = H;
            }
        });
    }

    public static int newW() {
        return getW;
    }
    public static int newH() {
        return getH;
    }
}
package com.arena.game;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Enemy extends JPanel{
    int x;
    int y;
    int SquareS;
    public Enemy(int SquareS) {
        this.SquareS = SquareS;

    }
    public void newxy(int x,int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        try {TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        paintComponent(this.getGraphics());
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(x, y, SquareS, SquareS);
    }
}
package com.arena.game;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class food extends JPanel{
    Random ran = new Random();
    int x;
    int y;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g ,int Score) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // ERROR LINE
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(x, y, Score, Score);
    }
    public food(int Difficulty,int Wid,int Hei) {

        int Score = ran.nextInt(ran.nextInt(Difficulty)+1);
        x = ran.nextInt(Wid)+1;
        y = ran.nextInt(Hei)+1;
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();y 
        }
        paintComponent(this.getGraphics(),Score);
    }
}
```

Sorry I couldn't just give a small snippet. (I didn't know where the problem really was) As I am still new to java and java graphics and still getting used to this type of code

Comment: As you wrote, you get an exception. Can you please add that exception to your post? Thank you.

Comment: you should at least be able to provide a stacktrace (and you should be able to read it, it tells you exactly on which line the problem occurs)

Comment: Will add that now

Comment: As you already marked the error line. I assume that `g` is null. Have you debugged your code and validated, that `g` is not null at that call?

Comment: no, not yet as I am not familiar with the debugging required in java graphics, but I shall try that now

Comment: yes, it is null

Comment: But what I do not know is how to make it not null...

Comment: don't call the paintComponent in the constructor, the instance isn't completely instantiated yet

Comment: So, where should I call it?

Comment: It's been some time since I worked with swing. But wasn't there some kind of `onDraw` or `onPaint` method, that gets invoked, when the component is actually drawn on the screen? You could overwrite it, as you inherit from JPanel.

Comment: Instead of calling `paintComponent()` directly, call `repaint()` instead. That will force a redraw of the component in the correct graphics thread. It will have the graphics object to pass to the `paintComponent()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your Food class and it works now. And for proper Java should be `Food`, not `food`:

```
package com.arena.game;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Food extends JPanel{
    Random ran = new Random();
    int x;
    int y;
    private int _score = 0;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // ERROR LINE
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(x, y, _score, _score);
    }

    public Food(int Difficulty,int Wid,int Hei) {

        _score = ran.nextInt(ran.nextInt(Difficulty)+1);
        x = ran.nextInt(Wid)+1;
        y = ran.nextInt(Hei)+1;
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```